# Computing $\int\limits_{0}^{\infty}(\sqrt{x}(1 + 3x^2))^{-1}\rm{d}x$ with the residue theorem

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

The integral is
\begin{equation}
I = \int\limits_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\rm{d}x}{\sqrt{x}(1 + 3x^2)}
\end{equation}
I cannot figure out how to solve this applying the Residue theorem, as I have not a closed curve... My function is neither odd or even, any ideas?

**EDIT:**

As I'm still looking for a complete solution I ask if someone can show how to compute the residue for the singularities on the positive half plane ($\Im{z}>0$), because anyway I try to calculate them I get the wrong result. Thanks in advance.

Comment: One thing you can do is sub $x=u^2$ and then use a semicircle in the upper half-plane...

Comment: the result should be $$\frac{1}{6}\pi\sqrt{2}\cdot 3^{3/4}$$

Comment: Hint: Use a keyhole contour in the complex-$x$ plane and compare the two parts along the positive real axis. (This is the same as @RonGordon's suggestion, but for the original variable.)

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner the result is exact, but it was not very helpful...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you perform the substitution $x=t^2$ you are left with
$$ \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{2\,dt}{1+3t^4} = \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{dt}{1+3t^4} $$
where the last integral equals $2\pi i$ times the sum of the residues of $\frac{1}{1+3t^4}$ at the simple poles in the upper half plane. That is a straightforward computation.

Comment: Yes this looked like the fastest computation, but what a bout the residue of the 4th degree polynomial? Is there a smartest way to compute? Or do I have to decompose the polynomial in 1st degree ones?

Comment: @opisthofulax: the roots of $1+3t^4$ are trivial!

Comment: Yes I know but for some reason when i calculate the residue on the positive half plane I have some problem with the final result, so I was wondering if there is an alternative method to check whether my calculations are right or not...

Comment: @opisthofulax: if $z_0$ is a simple pole for $f(z)=\frac{1}{g(z)}$, $$\text{Res}\left(f(z),z=z_0\right) = \lim_{z\to z_0} (z-z_0)f(z) = \frac{1}{g'(z_0)}$$ by De l'Hospital theorem. Maybe that helps.

Comment: Sorry, I know I'm a little bit slow-minded; I'm eventually doing something very wrong and bad, because I tried to calculate residue both way (by decomposing $$f(z) = \frac{1}{3}\frac{1}{\left(z + \frac{\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}\right)\left(z - \frac{\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}\right)\left(z + \frac{i\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}\right)\left(z - \frac{i\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}\right)}$$ and with the very smart method you suggested, involving De l'Hospital theorem. Anyway I get the result $$\frac{2\pi(1+i)}{3^{1/4}\sqrt{i}}$$ which is not the right one...

Comment: As long as I'm in the positive half plane I only have to consider the residue of the two singular point in this region right? So in the two points $z_1 = \frac{\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}$ and $z_2 = \frac{i\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}$, right?

Comment: @opisthofulax: exactly.

Comment: Well, so it must be a calculus mistake, as the result should be $$\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{2}\cdot3^{1/4}}$$ while I still get $\frac{2\pi(1+i)}{3^{1/4}\sqrt{i}}$

Comment: @opisthofulax: maybe you just forgot to sum the two residues and multiply them by $2\pi i$.

Comment: No... I'll post the calculus anyway, so it'll be clear: $$  \left[\frac{1}{\frac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}z}3z^4+1}\right]\Big|_{z = \frac{\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}} = \frac{1}{3^{1/4}4i\sqrt{i}}$$ and $$\left[\frac{1}{\frac{\rm{d}}{\rm{d}z}3z^4+1}\right]\Big|_{z = \frac{i\sqrt{i}}{3^{1/4}}} = \frac{1}{3^{1/4}4\sqrt{i}}$$. Then the sum of the residues is $$2\pi i\left[\frac{1}{3^{1/4}4i\sqrt{i}} + \frac{1}{3^{1/4}4\sqrt{i}}\right]$$... I can't still figure out where the error is...

Comment: Do you have any idea or a correct solution? I'm really going mad on this integral...

Comment: @opisthofulax: your solution is already correct, you just have to simplify your last expression. What is $\sqrt{i}$, for instance? Can you see it is $\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}$?

Comment: I didn't even thought of the polar expression $i^{1/2} = e^{i\pi/4} = \frac{(1+i)}{\sqrt{2}}$, I was panicking for nothing. Thank you so much!